# Isothermal coordinates in a orientable riemannian surface

Tags: differential-geometry

We know that any orientable riemannian surface has an isothermal coordinate around any point. This atlas provide an orientation to this surface?

Comment: You can always compose a chart with a reflection to get a chart with the opposite orientation (but retaining essentially any other nice property, e.g. isothermality).

Comment: So any orientable suface has an atlas formed by isothermal coordinates such that the change of parameters is always positive